# Disable button inside listview based on value - Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to disable button for a specific item inside custom listview based on value. But it disables the button for all items in listview. My CustomAdapter code is below

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);   

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtRef = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_jobpartid);
            holder.txtDate=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_date);
            holder.txtTime=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_time);
            holder.txtNotes=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_notes);
            holder.txtPick=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_pick);
            holder.txtVia=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_via);
            holder.txtDrop=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_drop);
            holder.txtPassengers=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_passangers);
            holder.txtSuitcases=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_luggages);
            holder.txtChildseat=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_childseat);
            holder.txtFlight=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_flight);
            holder.txtExpArrival=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_expArrival);
            holder.txtMeetnGreet=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_meetngreet);
            holder.txtVehicle=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_vehicle);
            holder.txtReturn=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_waitnrtn);
            holder.txtFee=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_fee);
            holder.txtTopup=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_topup);
            holder.txtPay=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_paymethod);
            holder.txtPrice=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_txt_price);
            holder.btnAccept=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_btnAccept);

            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(data.size()<=0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = ( job_details ) data.get( position );                                          

  holder.txtRef.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getRequestedJobPartID()));    
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String dateString = sdf.format(tempValues.getPickupDate());
            holder.txtDate.setText(dateString);    
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            dateString = sdf.format(tempValues.getPickupDate());
            holder.txtTime.setText(dateString);    
            holder.txtNotes.setText(tempValues.getNotes());    
            holder.txtPick.setText(tempValues.getPickupAddress());    
            holder.txtVia.setText(tempValues.getViaLocations());    
            holder.txtDrop.setText(tempValues.getDropoffAddress());                           holder.txtPassengers.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getPassengers()));    holder.txtSuitcases.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getSuitcases()));
            holder.txtChildseat.setText(tempValues.getChildSeat());
            holder.txtFlight.setText(tempValues.getFlightNumber());
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd  kk:mm");

            if(tempValues.getExpFlightArrival()!=null) {
                dateString = sdf.format(tempValues.getExpFlightArrival());
                holder.txtExpArrival.setText(dateString);    
            }    
            holder.txtMeetnGreet.setText(tempValues.getMeetAndGreet());    
            holder.txtVehicle.setText(tempValues.getVehicleType());    
            holder.txtReturn.setText(tempValues.getJourneyType());                                      holder.txtFee.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getBookingFee()));holder.txtTopup.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getAdjustment()));
            holder.txtPay.setText(tempValues.getPaymentMethod());
            holder.txtPrice.setText(tempValues.getTotalFare());
            Button btn1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_btnReject);
            Button btn=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_btnAccept);
//Checking the value and disabling/enabling the buttons
            if(tempValues.getRequestStatus()=="Accepted")
            {
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(false);
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(true);
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(true);
            }    

            Button btn2=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.lst_btnStart); 
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, "Start", tempValues.getRequestedJobPartID()));

//vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

        }
        return vi;
    }
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Also the click event on listview item does not work. I have tried removing buttons and also by putting the below lines in xml. I also tried setting focusable to flase in code.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Use tempValues.getRequestStatus().equals("Accepted") instead tempValues.getRequestStatus()=="Accepted"

Comment: Sure. This is one my dot.net habit. I will try and update you soon. Thanks.

Comment: @NandakishoreShetty Thank you. That worked.

Comment: I will add this as answer and please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
     tempValues.getRequestStatus().equals("Accepted")

instead

tempValues.getRequestStatus()=="Accepted"

Answer (score 1):

The == binary operator compares memory addresses.

```
if(tempValues.getRequestStatus().equal("Accepted"))
            {
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(false);
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(true);
                holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(true);
            }
```

**With respect to the String class:**

The equals() method compares the "value" inside String instances (on the heap) irrespective if the two object references refer to the same String instance or not. If any two object references of type String refer to the same String instance then great! If the two object references refer to two different String instances .. it doesn't make a difference. Its the "value" (that is: the contents of the character array) inside each String instance that is being compared.

Answer (score 0):

change == to .equal()

```
 if(tempValues.getRequestStatus().equal("Accepted"))
        {
            holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(false);
            holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(true);
            holder.btnAccept.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 if(tempValues.getRequestStatus()=="Accepted")
```

to:

```
 if(tempValues.getRequestStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Accepted"))
```

as it will ignore the case as well if tempValues.getRequestStatus() value is "accepted" then condition will be true.